# How to resolve 'duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64' from Xcode when you're starting out on Xcode?

Tags: xcode

I have these three files and they are not working, it gives the 'duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64'. I have an image describing what the error details. Does anyone know how to resolve it?

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>             /* printf definitions */


int main(void)
{
    //Problem inputs stored in memory locations for use later

    //None for this problem, as we are just printing "pretty lines"

    printf("Hello World\n");

    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

practice.h

```
#ifndef practice_h
#define practice_h

#include <stdio.h>

#endif /* practice_h */
```

practice.c

```
#include "practice.h"

/* Program to print a few lines on the screen */



int main(void)
{
    //Problem inputs stored in memory locations for use later

    //None for this problem, as we are just printing "pretty lines"

    printf("Hello World\n");

    getchar();

    return (0);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a function main() in main.c, and another function main() in practice.c. That's two. That's a duplicate.